# Filter products added within last 3 days in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, date, filter

Here is an object array products, each element has a string property named addedDate. Now I want to filter to get only those products added within last 3 day.

```js
let now = new Date();
let newProducts: IProduct[];

newProducts = this.products.filter(p => {
    new Date(p.dateAdded).getDate() + 3 >= now.getDate()});
   
console.log(newProducts);
```

unfortunately, I got nothing filtered out of products. Please help?  I

Comment: Can you add the example input array, and your expected output to the question, please?

Comment: You are missing a `return` (should be flagged by any decent linter, or static typing, ...). Note this code will fail at least when the two dates are in different months.

Comment: Be aware also that the filter will break close to the end of any month

Comment: Thanks to Andy and ASDFGerte, and especially tromgy as you did reminded me of the potential issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can get what I wanted as below, the solution may need to be optimized though.

```js
      let newProducts: IProduct[] = [];           

      for (let p of this.products)
      {
        let dTime = new Date(p.dateAdded).getTime();
        let nowTime = new Date().getTime();
        if (nowTime - dTime < 3 * 86400000)
        newProducts.push(p);        
      }
      
      console.log(newProducts);
```